# A python dictionary has multiple attributes for a key. How to find the minimum value among one of those attributes and return the key?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary as following:

```
<key1> "Position": double, "Speed": double, "Distance": 100.2
<key2> "Position": double, "Speed": double, "Distance": 98.2
<key3> "Position": double, "Speed": double, "Distance": 73.9
  .
  .
  .
<keyn> "Position": double, "Speed": double, "Distance": 25.89
```

I want to find which key has the minimum "Distance" value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a dict of dictionaries:

```
data = {
 'key1': {"Position": 0.0, "Speed": 0.0, "Distance": 100.2},
 'key2': {"Position": 0.0, "Speed": 0.0, "Distance": 98.2},
 'key3': {"Position": 0.0, "Speed": 0.0, "Distance": 73.9},
 'keyn': {"Position": 0.0, "Speed": 0.0, "Distance": 25.89}
}
```

then you can just use the `key` argument to `max()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
max(data, key=lambda d: data[d]['Distance'])

Out[]:
'key1'
```

Comment: it shows an error '\x15' and nothing else. no traceback

Comment: Would you also explain the arguments in the max() function? what is [d] here? an iterator for all keys? what is the role of lambda here?

Comment: it WORKD!! Amazing. Would you mind explaining the max function's parameters?

Comment: `lambda` creates a an anonymous function, in this case with one parameter `d`, each `d` is just a `key` in the `data` dictionary, so `data[d]['Distance']` just gets each `Distance` value as the way `max()` uses to determine which `key` in `data` is the maximum.